# Can't clear pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

This is my first time using pandas and I am trying to make a forloop that extracts mp3 links from a website and put them into a csv file. For each album link, it will make a new folder and a new csv file, then it will put the mp3s into the csv.

Everything works **BUT** I have one major problem - The dataframe keeps appending the data from the last loop into the current loop. So my dataframe's `list` keeps getting bigger and bigger.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

def mpull():
   albumlist()
   baseurl = "https://downloads.khinsider.com"
   alist = albumlist.albums_str
   llist = albumlist.link_str
   fullsoup = []
   for l, ab in zip(llist, alist):
      os.mkdir(ab)
      url = urllib.request.urlopen(l)
      content = url.read()
      soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
      for a in soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile('/*\.mp3')):
         df = pd.DataFrame([])
         fullsoup.append(baseurl+a['href'])
         remove_dup(fullsoup)
         df = pd.DataFrame(fullsoup)
      df.to_csv(ab+"/"+ab+".csv", index=False, header=False) 
      print(fullsoup)
mpull()
```

What I want is this:

```
007 everything or nothing:

https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/007-everything-or-nothing/EON-01-James-Bond-Theme.mp3
https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/007-everything-or-nothing/EON-02-Russian-Liar.mp3
#MORE 007 everything or nothing songs
```

What I am getting is this:

```
007 everything or nothing:
#songs from the last loop appear first for some reason
https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/007-blood-stone/01-%2520James%2520Bond-Blood%2520Stone%2520Theme%2520Song.mp3
https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/007-blood-stone/02-%2520M%2520Puts%2520Her%2520Trust%2520in%2520Bond.mp3
#Then the right songs appear afterwards 
https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/007-everything-or-nothing/EON-01-James-Bond-Theme.mp3
https://downloads.khinsider.com/game-soundtracks/album/007-everything-or-nothing/EON-02-Russian-Liar.mp3
#MORE 007 everything or nothing songs
```

What I tried:
I tried adding `del df` to the end of the loop like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

def mpull():
   albumlist()
   baseurl = "https://downloads.khinsider.com"
   alist = albumlist.albums_str
   llist = albumlist.link_str
   fullsoup = []
   for l, ab in zip(llist, alist):
      os.mkdir(ab)
      url = urllib.request.urlopen(l)
      content = url.read()
      soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
      for a in soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile('/*\.mp3')):
         df = pd.DataFrame([])
         fullsoup.append(baseurl+a['href'])
         remove_dup(fullsoup)
         df = pd.DataFrame(fullsoup)
      df.to_csv(ab+"/"+ab+".csv", index=False, header=False) 
      del def
      print(fullsoup)
mpull()
```

But that didn't seem to do anything or rather - it was still appending the last loop's dataframe into the current csv iteration.

Any ideas would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!! Instead of trying to delete the dataframe `df`. I needed to delete the `fullsoup` list on every loop iteration so it doesn't keep the list's data on every loop.

```
def mpull():
   albumlist()
   baseurl = "https://downloads.khinsider.com"
   alist = albumlist.albums_str
   llist = albumlist.link_str
   for l, ab in zip(llist, alist):
      fullsoup = []
      os.mkdir(ab)
      url = urllib.request.urlopen(l)
      content = url.read()
      soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
      for a in soup.findAll('a',href=re.compile('/*\.mp3')):
         df = pd.DataFrame([])
         fullsoup.append(baseurl+a['href'])
         # remove_dup(fullsoup)
         df = pd.DataFrame(fullsoup)
      print(fullsoup)
      del fullsoup
      df.to_csv(ab+"/"+ab+".csv", index=False, header=False) 
mpull()
```

Comment: if you set `fullsoup = []` inside `for`-loop then you don't need `del fullsoup`. In original version you set `fullsoup = []` before `for`-loop so you needed `fullsoup.clear()` to remove previous values.

Comment: I tried that before hand and that didn't work as expected. Instead of getting all the mp3s from the webpage, into a list, it would only get one link, and then move on to the next. So I had to put the `fullsoup` inside the first for loop (instead of the second) for that to not occur. Everything is working well except for some webpage errors sometimes. But that is ok with me :)